# Could not find method_source-1.0.0.gem for installation

Tags: redmine

I want to install redmine as a source by referring to the URL below.

https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

When I run the below in "Step 4 - Dependencies installation", I get an error.

/opt/redmine/redmine-5.0.0$ sudo bundler install

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
:
Installing method_source 1.0.0
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find method_source-1.0.0.gem for installation
:
  /usr/local/bin/bundler:25:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/bundler:25:in `'
:
An error occurred while installing method_source (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  actionpack-xml_parser was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
    railties was resolved to 6.1.4.7, which depends on
      method_source
```

Answer (score 0):

Im fixed this error by install gem manually:

```
gem install method_source
```